# Simple example of gang scheduling of processes in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a pool of processes that need to be executed. I would like to fully utilize the machine, so that all CPUs are executing processes. I do not want to over-subscribe the system, so what i really want is #executing_processes=#cpus at any given moment. 
I also need to store the stdout,stderr and return code of each completed processes.
How can this be achieved in Python?

EDIT: by 'process' i mean a shell process.

Comment: "#executing_processes=#cpus" will underutilize your system.  Since a single process can rarely use 100% of resources, you should probably remove this restriction on your question.

Comment: Generally speaking, your statement is correct, but in my particular case the each process reaches 100% CPU utilization.

Comment: @zr: Absolutely 100%, all the time?  It's very unlikely to have a process which never makes a single system request and never waits for a resource, but ramps up to 100% CPU usage immediately.  That sounds like the kind of artificial constraint that only appears in a homework problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about *your own, Python-implemented* processes:

The [**`multiprocessing`**](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module gives you the ability to spawn multiple processes.  In particular, it sounds like you would want to create [multiprocessing.cpu_count](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.cpu_count) numbers of processes, potentially in a `Pool`.

If you are talking about separate programs that you want to *execute through the shell*:

The [**`subprocess`**](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module will let you spawn processes through its [`Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) class, which has parameters for `stdin`, `stdout`, `sterr` that accept file-like objects.  [`Popen.returncode`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode) can be used to check the return code.

Comment: I was referring to the latter.